# Splitting Dataframe into two DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dateframe which have unique as well as repeated records on the basis of number. Now i want to split the dataframe into two dataframe. In first dataframe i need to copy only unique rows and in second dataframe i want all repeated rows. For example

```
     id   name     number
     1    Shan     101
     2    Shan     101
     3    John     102
     4    Michel   103
```

The two splitted dataframe should be like

Unique

```
      id    name    number
      3     John    102
      4     Michel  103
```

Repeated

```
      id   name     number
      1    Shan     101
      2    Shan     101
```

Comment: I have tried this but it return count against numbers
df.groupBy("number").count().select("*").where("count > 1")

i need all repeated rows with all columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you tried could probably get you there.

Your data looks like this

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array(
     (1, "Shan",     101),
     (2, "Shan", 101),
     (3, "John", 102),
     (4, "Michel", 103)
     )).toDF("id","name","number")
```

Then you yourself suggest grouping and counting. If you do it like this

```
 val repeatedNames = df.groupBy("name").count.where(col("count")>1).withColumnRenamed("name","repeated").drop("count")
```

then you could actually get all the way by doing something like this afterwards:

```
 val repeated = df.join(repeatedNames, repeatedNames("repeated")===df("name")).drop("repeated")

 val distinct = df.except(repeated)

 repeated show
+---+----+------+
| id|name|number|
+---+----+------+
|  1|Shan|   101|
|  2|Shan|   101|
+---+----+------+

 distinct show
+---+------+------+
| id|  name|number|
+---+------+------+
|  4|Michel|   103|
|  3|  John|   102|
+---+------+------+
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AtifShahzad If this answer your question, could you then please mark it as answered? This will removed the it from the list of open questions as well as give me some points in credit.